# Unfair Coin Toss

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The probability of the coin landing on head is 60%. We will do 40 trials. What is the probability of getting 4 consecutive heads during 40 trials? Assume each trial is independent.

First I find out that there are $2^{40}$ possible series of heads and tails. Each sequence is binomially distributed with n = 40 and p = 0.6. So we can take the sum of these $2^{40}$ probabilities to get the denominator. For the numerator, we need to perhaps first calculate how many sequences do not have 4 consecutive heads, and then subtract the probability from the total.

If the sequence cannot have 4 consecutive heads, then it also cannot have 5, 6, and so on, consecutive heads. But it can have 1, 2, and 3 consecutive heads.

One point worth noting is that we can have ...HTHT... in the sequence but still has only one consecutive head. The same logic goes to 2, and 3. We can have ...HHTHTTTHH... There are more than 2 heads in the entire sequence but we only have 2 consecutive heads at most.

Comment: Each trial consists of a single flip?  You say "I have tried taking the cube of 0.6 and multiply the answer by 37".  Okay, you are thinking of 37 trials where each trial is "flip a coin 3 times".  Then there are 37 trials since the "trials" can start with the first flip, the second flip, ..., up to the 37th  flip.  (Not the 38th, 39th, 40th since there would not be 4 flips left.)  But why "cube of 0,6"?  The probability of **four** consecutive heads is $0.6^4$.

Comment: Each trial is a single flip and I should take the 4th power of 0.6. See edit. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

After your third edit, you had $37 \times 0.6^4 = 4.7952$, which is the expected number of four heads in a row (including overlaps, so THHHHHHT has three examples of HHHH)

It is greater than $1$ so cannot possibly be a probability

You can find the probability of at least one case of four heads in a row various ways.  One is to use a recurrence for $p_T(n)$, the probability that $n$ trials does not have four heads in a row and the last trial is not heads. Such a state must end with tails preceded by $0$, $1$, $2$, or $3$ heads, so you can say

$$f_T(n)=0.4(f_T(n-1)+0.6f_T(n-2)+0.6^2f_T(n-3)+0.6^3f_T(n-4))$$

and you can start with $f_T(0)=1$ but zero for negative values

Rather than solving this, it is probably easier to calculate individual values and this will lead to  $f_T(37)\approx 0.03586, f_T(38)\approx 0.03339, f_T(39)\approx 0.03109, f_T(40)\approx 0.02894$ and you want $$1-(f_T(40)+0.6f_T(39)+0.6^2f_T(38)+0.6^3f_T(37))$$ which works out to about $0.93264$

Comment: How does recurrence account for the cases when there are multiple occurrences of 2 consecutive heads? i.e. ...TTTHHTHHTTTTHH...